EF fails when Inserting only one out of two properties of the same type
I have this closure table that is supposed to make easier to get all replies of a comment, their replies, all replies to the comment ( even distant inheritants), but when I try to insert the parent - it inserts the CHILD as the parent. I don't recall if I had ever encountered such issue.
public class ReplyClosure
 {
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public int ParentId { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey(nameof(ParentId))]

     public PostReply Parent { get; set; } = null!;

     public int ChildId { get; set; }
     [ForeignKey(nameof(ChildId))]
     public PostReply Child { get; set; } = null!;

     public int Depth { get; set; } 
     
 }

public class PostReply
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ForumUserId { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ForumUserId))]
    public ForumUser ForumUser { get; set; } = null!;

    public int PostId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(PostId))]

    public Post Post { get; set; } = null!;

    [Column(TypeName = "Text")]
    public string Content { get; set; } = String.Empty;


    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; } 

    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(ReplyClosure.Parent))]
    public virtual List<ReplyClosure> Parents { get; set; } = new List<ReplyClosure>();


    [InverseProperty(nameof(ReplyClosure.Child))]
    public virtual List<ReplyClosure> Children { get; set; } = new List<ReplyClosure>();

}

The problematic code is this:
I tried to write this in too many ways and none worked and for some reason I insert the child
in the place of parent. I don't know why it is happening. It probably has something to do when trying to create a reply at the same time as reply closure. I tried using the other way around - insert the reply and use the navigation property to add the parent. It did not work either.
PostReply postReply = new PostReply
 {
     CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
     PostId = replyViewModel.PostId,
     UserId = GetUserId(),
     Content = replyViewModel.Content,
     IsDeleted = false
 };
 var closure = new ReplyClosure
 {
     ParentId = replyViewModel.ParentId, // this is the correct id, confirmed
     Depth = replyViewModel.Depth,
     Child = postReply
 };
          
 await _context.RepliesClosures.AddAsync(closure);
 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

The context contains the following db relationship description:
builder.Entity<PostReply>()
.HasOne(entry => entry.Post)
.WithMany(entry => entry.PostsReplies)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
  
builder.Entity<ReplyClosure>()
.HasOne(entry => entry.Parent)
.WithMany(entry => entry.Children)
.HasForeignKey(entry => entry.ParentId)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
 
builder.Entity<ReplyClosure>()
.HasOne(entry => entry.Child)
.WithMany(entry => entry.Parents)
.HasForeignKey(entry => entry.ChildId)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

Ps. I know there is probably a better way to design a comment area in a simulated forum app, but this was the bare minimum I could think of. I know I might be forgetting something, just not sure what it is. Thanks
I tried to use the inverse navigation properties - to no avail, I can't use a raw sql transaction and I also tried chat gpt, all my db relations seem correct. I want to create the two entities at the same time and use saveChanges just once. I tried first inserting the reply, saving and then inserting the closure. It still inserts the child in both places - the parentId and the childId, so it must be the way I define the relations in the dbcontext or something.

What is the actual exception or observed incorrect behaviour when you run that? You are using both attributes and model builder to define the relationships, usually you should use one or the other as if they differ one will be ignored so you can be left confused by "correct" configuration that isn't actually used.

There was no exception.. that's why I was so baffled. Debugged and all the values were correct until context save changes. I kept checking db afterwards, each time the child id went into both places - parentId and childId into the closures table. There were no exceptions thrown.

This configuration:
[InverseProperty(nameof(ReplyClosure.Parent))]
public virtual List<ReplyClosure> Parents { get; set; } = new List<ReplyClosure>();

Does not match this config:
builder.Entity<ReplyClosure>()
    .HasOne(entry => entry.Parent)
    .WithMany(entry => entry.Children)
    .HasForeignKey(entry => entry.ParentId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

The second fluent config looks correct, using the attributes instead should be:
[InverseProperty(nameof(ReplyClosure.Child))]
public virtual List<ReplyClosure> Parents { get; set; } = new List<ReplyClosure>();

[InverseProperty(nameof(ReplyClosure.Parent))]
public virtual List<ReplyClosure> Children { get; set; } = new List<ReplyClosure>();

If you are seeing the wrong FK updated I think EF is using the attributes and ignoring the correct fluent config. I'd recommend using one or the other to avoid this possible confusion.

Thank you so much! Yes, that was the issue INDEED.
